# Two row values into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Can anyone please tell me how I can have show two row values , two different column value in one row an two columns. Below is the table :

---

```
Test ID     Total Employees    Response Score     Eval Score
1                7                    4.24              0
1                7                       0              4.78
2                13                   4.52              0
2                13                      0              4.89
```

---

So I am looking for the output:

---

```
Test ID     Total Employees    Response Score     Eval Score
1                7                    4.24             4.78
2                13                   4.52             4.89
```

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function with a `GROUP BY` to get the result:

```
select TestId, 
   totalEmployees, 
   max(ResponseScore) responseScore, 
   max(EvalScore) EvalScore
from yourTable
group by TestId, totalEmployees;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select [Test ID], 
       [Total Employees], 
       max([Response Score]) as [Response Score],
       max([Eval Score]) as [Eval Score]
from your_table
group by [Test ID], [Total Employees]
```